# Compile time warning about memset on non plain old data

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

I'm working on a large code base, converting some old C modules into C++. I want to add a C++ object to a struct, but some users of this struct `memset` it, which is unfortunate for the object that I want to put in the struct.

How can I detect at compile time that this is being done, so that I can eliminate all use of `memset` on such a struct that is no longer POD?

Comment: Does `grep`ing for `memset` turn up too many results to check manually? Otherwise, I don't see a way for the compiler to check this.

Comment: @arne That's part of the problem, yes.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not sure if compiler will help you there by directly providing some compilation flags. If it does, good for you. Use that. End of story.

If it doesn't, then maybe this will help you. Since you're converting your code from C to C++, that means all the usage of memset is without `std::` namespace. So take advantage of this fact and `#define memset` as:

```
 #define memset memset_if_pod_else_error()
```

Here `memset_if_pod_else_error` is a function written by you (i.e you have to implement it). You could make it template so as to deduce the type of argument and then detect whether the type is POD or not. If it is POD, then that is fine and call `std::memset` internally, else raise error.

Metafunctions like `std::enable_if` and `std::is_pod` will help you to implement this function.

Here is a minimal demo of this idea:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstring>

auto ptr_memset =  std::memset; //store this a pointer

template<typename T>
using VoidPtr = typename std::enable_if<std::is_pod<T>::value, void*>::type;

#define memset memset_if_pod_else_error

template<typename T>
VoidPtr<T> memset_if_pod_else_error(T *data, int ch, size_t count) 
{
      return ptr_memset(data, ch, count);
}

struct pod {};
struct nonpod { nonpod() {} };

int main()
{
    pod p;
    nonpod np;

    memset(&p, 0, sizeof(p));

    memset(&np, 0, sizeof(np));  //this is error!
}
```

The second call to `memset` generates this error:

> error: no matching function for call to 'memset_if_pod_else_error'
>          **memset(&np, 0, sizeof(np));**
>          ^~~~~~

[Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=2ed21d0f504e9e48a379cc09ed114701-e223fd4a885a77b520bbfe69dda8fb91).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good idea. The old C module is used thousands of places in newer C++ code as well, so unfortunately for me this will only partially solve my problem.

Comment: @Henrik: I don't see any problem. You could implement the function accordingly. See my demo. Hope that gives your *better* idea.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
auto orig_memset =  std::memset;
#define memset checked_memset

template <class T>
void* checked_memset(T* ptr, int value, size_t num) {
  static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "memset on non-POD");
  return original_memset(data, value, num);
}
```

Or, if you're interested only in finding violations for your particular struct:

```
auto original_memset =  std::memset;
#define memset checked_memset

template <class T>
void* checked_memset(T* ptr, int value, size_t num) {
  static_assert(!std::is_same<T, YOUR_STRUCT_HERE>::value, "memset used on YOUR_STRUCT_HERE");
  return original_memset(data, value, num);
}
```

Comment: the return type should probably be void*, not T*.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can detect use of `memset` on non-POD data at compile-time.

What you can do is add some an extra field which is set in the constructor, and then checked in any other member functions. Something like this:

```
 class X
 {
    const int MAGIC = 123456789;
    int magic;
    ...
  public:
    X() : magic(MAGIC) { ... }
    ... 
    void do_stuff()
    {
       check_magic();
       ... 
    } 
  private: 
    void check_magic() 
    { 
      if (magic != MAGIC) { ... do something to indicate bad state ... }; 
    }
 };
```

Obviously, this could be done "only on debug builds".

Comment: If the constructor can be made `constexpr`, couldn't this also be checked by a static assertion?

Comment: The problem isn't in the construction, the problem is that the `memset` doesn't really care what you are feeding into it, and will simply splat straight over anything you feed into it - which means that the you have to check the `magic` after (potential call to) `memset`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case isntead of trying to find all the problem areas, I would suggest just preventing them in the first place. Specifically, don't add any C++ capabilities to the existing C structs but instead write classes with an appropriate interfcace that contain instances of the C data structures. Then you maintain total backwards compatibility with the old structures and code as well as adding the new C++ capabilities you're interested in.